# Irreducibility of $x^2 + 1$ in $\Bbb F_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I can show that in field formed by roots of $x^{4 \cdot 2^n + 1} - x$, the polynomial $x^2 + 1$ factors into linear factors. This gives $p = 4 \cdot 2^n+1\equiv 1 \pmod 4$. But how if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_p$?

So far, I think if $x^2 + 1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb F_p$ then $x(x^p-1)$ should not contain a factor $x^2 + 1$. Any value other than $p=4n+1$ does not give this factor. But why $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ in particular? **Why not $p \equiv 0 \pmod 4$ or $p \equiv 2 \pmod 4$**?

Here it is done in [example 1.0.3.](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/algebra/notes/07.pdf)

> Workout: I was too stupid to realize that $p$ was prime.
>   No primes have the form $p = 4n$ or $p = 4n+2 $

Comment: Hint: look at the group $\Bbb F_p^*$ of units of $F_p$. This group is a cyclic group of $p - 1$ elements; say it is generated by $\alpha$. Because $-1$ has order $2$ (except if $p = 2$; that's a separate case), it must be equal to $\alpha^{(p-1)/2}$. Now, when is this element a square?

Comment: @Magdiragdag when $p-1 = 4n$??

Comment: Yes, indeed. And, in particular, if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, it is not a square, so in that case $x^2 + 1$ does not factor into linear factors.

Comment: @Magdiragdag I got confused, by not $p \equiv 2 \pmod 4$?

Comment: $p$ is prime and if $p \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, then $p = 2$. That's a special case, since then $-1 = 1$ and $x^2 + 1 = (x + 1)^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $x^2+1$ factors into linear polynomials if the field has a fourth root of unity.

Comment: The numbers $\;\pm1\;$ are fourth roots of unity in any characteristic (but in characteristic two they're the same), yet it is false the polynomial $\;x^2+1\;$ is reducible if $\;p=3\pmod 4\;$ . What is true is that the polynomial is reducible iff the field has a square root of $\;-1\;$ , which is not the same...

Comment: He meant a primitive 4th root of unity

Comment: @user1952009 Yup, I bet he may have meant that...

Comment: My question is about for what form of $p$, the field does not have fourth root of unity. Could you please explain me how ONLY $p=4n+3$ makes $x^2+1$ irreducible in $\Bbb F_p$ BUT NOT $p=3n$ or $p=3n+2$?